# ReactDOM.render cannot find my div element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I am getting the classic error:

> Error caught during routing:  Error: Target container is not a DOM
> element.

on this line of code:

```
ReactDOM.render(<GamerTag game={this.model} />, document.getElementById("gameDescription"));
```

I am rendering that React dom inside a Backbone view.

`gameDescription` is the ID of a div in my view's template where the React component is being rendered.

Like everyone says, put your main **js** file at the bottom of your main index file.

And I did, I put `<script src="~/dist/app.js"></script>` right before the ending `</body>` tag.

But I still get the error.

I know the div exists, because when I view the source in the browser, I see it.

Also, if I use `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))` inside the ReactDOM.render,
it works fine...well except for the fact that it's at the bottom of my page where I don't want it to be.

So I am horrid besides myself, what other options or things can I try?  I am out of clues.

Thanks you!

Comment: Maybe have a look at `ReactDOM.createPortal(child, container)`

Comment: @otejiri thanks! I just tried it, and same exact error :(

Answer (score 1):

Your element doesn't exist when react is trying to render your component.
I'm guessing this is because your backbone view isn't rendered at the time that react is trying to render the component.

An easy way to check this is to put a `debugger;` statement in your code just before your `ReactDOM.render()` call, and while stopped, open your DevTools, and look at the DOM and search for you element.
Or just open the console and run `document.getElementById('gameDescription')` and see if it's actually there.

Comment: Thanks, I did that and I see that it's `null`.  So now I know it doesn't exist yet.  Is this fixable?  Or is there no way to get this to work?

Comment: I'm not familiar with backbone, but if you can subscribe to an event that will notify you when backbone is done initial render, then you can trigger your react code at that point.